# How to prevent application file deleted when uninstall the app in android

Tags: android, image, file, download

```
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(file_url);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setTitle("")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyApp", tsLong.toString() + ".jpg");
```

The path to download file is here:

```
new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyApp")
```

I found that once the app is uninstall the folder is also deleted, how to preserve that ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/02/09/changes-downloadmanager-behavior.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the information, as the advice is stop using download manager, what is the alternative? thanks

Comment: Use your favorite HTTP client API (OkHttp, Volley, `HttpUrlConnection`, etc.), from your own foreground `IntentService`.